# How can I handle multiple lines at once while reading from a file?

Tags: python

The standard Python approach to working with files using the `open()` function to create a 'file object' `f` allows you to either load the entire file into memory at once using `f.read()` or to read lines one-by-one using a `for` loop:

```
with open('filename') as f:
    # 1) Read all lines at once into memory:
    all_data = f.read()

    # 2) Read lines one-by-one:
    for line in f:
        # Work with each line
```

I'm searching through several large files looking for a pattern that might span multiple lines.  The most intuitive way to do this is to read line-by-line looking for the beginning of the pattern, and then to load in the next few lines to see where it ends:

```
with open('large_file') as f:

    # Read lines one-by-one:
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("beginning"):
            # Load in the next line, i.e.
            nextline = f.getline(line+1)  # ??? #
            # or something
```

The line I've marked with `# ??? #` is my own pseudocode for what I imagine this should look like.

My question is, does this exist in Python?  Is there any method for me to access other lines as needed while keeping the cursor at `line` and without loading the entire file into memory?

**Edit**  Inferring from the responses here and other reading, the answer is "No."

Comment: You would set a "gather" flag, and then use that flag to decide what to do.

Comment: `nextline = f.readline()` should work. You don't need to tell it the line number, it just reads the next line.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
gather = []
for line in f:
    if gather:
        gather.append(line)
        if "ending" in line:
            process( ''.join(gather) )
            gather = []       
    elif line.startswith("beginning"):
        gather = [line]
```

Although in many cases it's easier just to load the whole file into a string and search it.

You may want to `rstrip` the newline before appending the line.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the interesting lines into a list while going line-wise through the file:

```
with open("file.txt","w") as f:
    f.write("""
a
b
------    
c
d
e
####
g
f""")

interesting_data = []
inside = False
with open ("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        # start of interesting stuff
        if line.startswith("---"):
            inside = True

        # end of interesting stuff
        elif line.startswith("###"):
            inside = False

        # adding interesting bits
        elif inside:
            interesting_data.append(line)

print(interesting_data)
```

to get

```
['c', 'd', 'e']
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for `.readline()`, which does exactly that. Here is a sketch to proceed to the line where a pattern starts.

```py
with open('large_file') as f:
    line = f.readline()

    while not line.startswith("beginning"):
        line = f.readline()
        
        # end of file
        if not line:
            print("EOF")
            break
    
    # do_something with line, get additional lines by 
    # calling .readline() again, etc.
```